# Firestore query on Kotlin from Non-Activity class

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple Android app with a RecyclerView in a Fragment that gets the data from Firestore via a presenter. My problem is that when I run the Firestore Query, the code after the query executes without waiting for the Query to finish...

It probably has to do with queries running not on main thread, but I'm quite a beginner at Kotlin/Android so don't really know how to handle this.

Here is the basic code in the Presenter:

```
fun fetchArticles():MutableList<Articulo> {

        val results = mutableListOf<Articulo>()
        val data = MainActivity.db.collection("articulos")
            .whereGreaterThan("id", 25)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for(document in documents) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data.[id]}")

                    //... Create some objects with the data to append to results...

                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }
        Log.w(TAG, "Returning ${results.size} results")
        return results
    }
```

The "returning results..." Log prints well before the Logs inside the SuccessListener.

Here is the console output:

```
2020-06-06 11:33:07.201 3766-3766/com.mypackage W/Presenter: Returning 0 results
2020-06-06 11:33:07.216 3766-3800/com.mypackage W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11925000 but found 11743470
2020-06-06 11:33:07.219 3766-3800/com.mypackage E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2
2020-06-06 11:33:07.220 3766-3800/com.mypackage W/Firestore: (21.4.3) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException: Google Play Services not available
2020-06-06 11:33:07.296 3766-3800/com.mypackage W/art: Before Android 4.1, method double java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextDouble(double, double) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
2020-06-06 11:33:07.296 3766-3800/com.mypackage W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextInt(int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
2020-06-06 11:33:07.296 3766-3800/com.mypackage W/art: Before Android 4.1, method long java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextLong(long, long) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
2020-06-06 11:33:07.319 3766-3802/com.mypackage W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-06-06 11:33:07.352 3766-3797/com.mypackage W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11743470
2020-06-06 11:33:07.489 3766-3797/com.mypackage W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
2020-06-06 11:33:07.495 3766-3797/com.mypackage W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11743470
2020-06-06 11:33:08.871 3766-3766/com.mypackage W/Presenter: abc_art_0026 => 26
2020-06-06 11:33:08.871 3766-3766/com.mypackage W/Presenter: abc_art_0027 => 27
2020-06-06 11:33:08.872 3766-3766/com.mypackage W/Presenter: abc_art_0028 => 28
2020-06-06 11:33:08.872 3766-3766/com.mypackage W/Presenter: abc_art_0030 => 30
2020-06-06 11:33:08.872 3766-3766/com.mypackage W/Presenter: abc_art_0031 => 31
2020-06-06 11:33:08.873 3766-3766/com.mypackage W/Presenter: abc_art_0032 => 32
```

Comment: Update Google Play service from the SDK manager.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick. I updated it but stille get the google play service error. However with another emulator that has newer API I don't get the Google Play service error but still the same behaviour regarding the Firestore query function...

Comment: `get()` is asynchronous and returns immediately.  The callback is invoked some time later, after the function returns.  You will need to adopt some for of asynchronous programming technique to handle this correctly (e.g. coroutines, LiveData).